# XCode Crash Log NSMutableDictionary Nil Check Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

My Xcode crash log points to this line of code where it is crashing:

```
if(contentDict != nil && [contentDict count] > 0) {
```

I would have thought that this could not crash, since it is checking for 'nil' first, and with the '&&' it would not check any further.  Could it be failing on the previous line?  I have 2 crash logs that point to the exact same line number.  Below is the method it comes from:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
channelIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

BOOL reachable = [self networkReachable];
if (!reachable) {
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kContent];       
    contentDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    if(contentDict == nil || [contentDict count] == 0) {
        contentDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kHistory];       
    historyDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    if(historyDict == nil || [historyDict count] == 0) {
        historyDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
}

if(selectedIndex == 0) {
    if(contentDict != nil && [contentDict count] > 0) {
        NSArray *keys = [contentDict allKeys];
        keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector (compare:)];  
        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [contentDict objectForKey:key]);
            Content *content = [contentDict objectForKey:key];
            if (![channelIndex containsObject:content.channelName])
            {            
                [channelIndex addObject:content.channelName];
            }        
        }
    }
} else {
    if(historyDict != nil && [historyDict count] > 0) {
        NSArray *keys = [historyDict allKeys];
        keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector (compare:)];  
        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [historyDict objectForKey:key]);
            Content *content = [historyDict objectForKey:key];
            if (![channelIndex containsObject:content.channelName])
            {            
                [channelIndex addObject:content.channelName];
            }        
        }
    }
}
return [channelIndex count];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]` returns an autoreleased object. Possibly that's your issue. Try to retain the result before you use it. Checking for `nil` won't help you if the variable points to a memory region that contains garbage because it has been auto-released.

Comment: I am assuming that I need to do this: contentDict = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]retain];

Comment: Is it necessary to remove the "retain" attribute from my property?

Comment: Lastly, it does not make sense to me that I would need to do that, since it just grabbed the objects from NSUserDefaults, and NSKeydUnarchiver was putting these deserialized objects into the NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: See @jlehr's answer: You're using the instance variable, not the property. If you use `self.contentDict = ...` then you don't need to call `retain` on the result of `unarchiveObjectWithData` because your property takes care of that (retains it). If you access the ivar directly (as you're doing in your code), you need to call `retain` because you are bypassing the setter.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is only setting the `contentDict` instance variable when the network is not reachable, so the first question would be: how is it getting set when the network *is* reachable? In all likelihood, it's being set somewhere else and not properly retained, so the dictionary is getting deallocated before you do the check.

Here are some suggestions:

1. Prefix your instance variables with an underscore, e.g. `_contentDict` rather than `contentDict`.
2. Avoid directly referencing instance variables in methods other than `init...`, `dealloc`, and getter/setter pairs. Use properties instead.
3. Don't bother checking for `nil` -- it's irrelevant here (messages to `nil` return zero for all non-struct return types).
4. Make sure you understand the rules for memory management. If you're compiling with ARC enabled: [Advanced Memory Mangement Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html); Otherwise:  [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226).